# Converting Array to JSON using SwiftyJSON

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I'm looking for a quick way to map a a 2-dim array to JSON.  I'm using SwiftyJSON and have hit a brick wall (I'm a hardware guy lol). Thank you!

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

var myPlaceArray = [Int:[String: Any]]()
myPlaceArray[0] = [
  "lat" : "2.590",
  "long" : "170.9"
  ]

myPlaceArray[1] = [
  "lat" : "42.90",
  "long" : "70.9"
]

//I can do this
let json = JSON(myPlaceArray[1]!)
print(json)

//but I cant do this
let jsonIndexed = JSON(myPlaceArray)
print(jsonIndexed[0] )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not declaring an array with this statement:

```
var myPlaceArray = [Int:[String: Any]]()
```

Instead, what you've declared above is a dictionary where the key is an Int and the values are dictionaries.

What you need is the following:

```
var myPlaceArray = [[String: Any]]()
```

Now, you can assign array elements as you did and you should be able to access the array as you wanted via your code. Give it a try and see :) If you run into any issues, comment here and I'll take a look.

Comment: Happy to help :) I know that dictionary and array notation can be a bit confusing at times. And if the above helped, please mark the answer as "correct" so that it helps others too.